# How can I change the Windows 7 Logon Screen wallpaper?

Tags: windows-7, login-screen, lock-screen

Is there an easy (and free) way to change the Logon Screen wallpaper in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to do it manually, you can use the [tweaks.com utility](http://tweaks.com/articles/39468/customizing-logon-screen-background-in-windows-7/). I've used it on Win 7 Pro x64, works like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a post from [James O'Neil's blog](http://blogs.technet.com/jamesone/archive/2009/05/07/customizing-the-windows-7-logon-screen-no-additional-tools-required.aspx) at Microsoft Technet that explains how it can be done.

> A few of people have noticed that I’m
>   running Windows 7 with a customized
>   logon screen, and a couple of them
>   asked me if I used “logon studio”
>   which (as I understand it) rummages
>   round inside some of the image
>   resources buried in DLL files.
>
> In Windows 7 we have provided a
>   registry key for OEMS to turn on
>   custom backgrounds it’s under
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Background
>   and the name is OEMBackground, you can
>   add it if it isn’t there – it’s a
>   DWORD 1 indicates use the custom
>   backgrounds and 0 means don’t. **Beware,
>   if you change Windows themes this gets
>   reset – which implies the theme covers
>   the background as well.**
>
> Once the option is enabled you need to
>   create files in the
>   %windir%\system32\oobe\info\backgrounds
>   folder, the names are
>   BackgroundHeightxWidth.JPG and
>   BackgroundDefault.jpg so for this
>   laptop I have a default and
>   Background1920x1400.You can use this
>   make your corporate Machine all more
>   corporate or your personal machine
>   that bit more personal.  According the
>   Windows 7 center  where (I think) I
>   first saw the tip the file size need
>   to be under 256KB. If you want to
>   customize the original background you
>   find it’s named background.bmp in the
>   OOBE folder (oobe for those who don’t
>   know is Out Of Box Experience in
>   Microsoft speak).

Comment: I took the liberty of quoting James, to make it easier