# How to Make Windows 7 Shutdown Have a Black Screen

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, shutdown

I would like to configure my Windows 7 system to not show the big blue shutdown screen and instead just show a black screen while it does its business.  I have seen how to do the boot with no GUI but what about the shutdown? Is there a registry setting or option that prevents the blue "Shutting Down..." screen from showing at all?

Comment: I think this is unwanted behavior, because user could accidentaly unplug a PC when it's shutting down (or even worse - when updating).

Comment: @gronostaj is right, simply turn-off your monitor

Comment: @gronostaj I would disagree. Lots of people leave their PC on while turning the monitor off. I look (and would hope others would do the same) at the case lights before starting to unplug stuff. There may be a very good reason why this question was asked.

Comment: When I shutdown my Windows 7 computer my monitor turns itself off. Its not clear what "big blue shutdown screen" they are talking about exactly.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm sure you have seen [some](http://i.stack.imgur.com/c0GJ6.png) or [all](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8UE7P.png) of [these](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G8C20.png) screens.

Comment: @Karan - Yes...Of course...which is the reason I wanted clarification.  The description used by the author was not clear.

Answer (score 2):

The shutdown screen wallpaper can be changed, but the same wallpaper is also used for the logon and lock screens as well. If you don't mind all those being black (excluding the text messages and buttons of course), follow the instructions as specified in this question: [How can I change the Windows 7 Logon Screen wallpaper?](https://superuser.com/questions/25647) and add a custom completely black wallpaper.

Better still, if you have access to the **Group Policy Editor** in your version of Windows use that as detailed [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/112110/how-to-set-a-custom-logon-screen-background-on-windows-7) to enable the custom background option instead of manually setting the *OEMBackground* DWORD value in the registry. The reason for this is that unlike the registry edit the Group Policy setting will persist even when you change your desktop theme.