# How to mod/create a loginui.exe (Login Screen)

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

How can I modify my current **Windows 7** Login Screen?

I'm really bored with that default red OEM screen. A registry key, or a place where the images are- may be useful.

Please point out more than one methods if possible and mark the best/safest one.

**NOTE:-** I want to change not only the wallpaper but the whole design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the Windows 7 Logon Screen wallpaper?](http://superuser.com/questions/25647/how-can-i-change-the-windows-7-logon-screen-wallpaper)

Comment: @DavidPostill I want to change the whole design

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change the whole design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XP used GINA (Graphical Identification and Authentication) based logon architecture, so you could build your own custom version to replace LogonUI.exe.

From Vista onwards Winlogon is the Windows module that performs interactive logon for a logon session. Winlogon behaviour can be customised by implementing and registering a **Credential Provider**. The relevant shell interfaces are listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

More information to get you started:

- [Create Custom Login Experiences With Credential Providers For Windows Vista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx)
- [How to Build Custom Logon UIs in Windows Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/07/30/how-to-build-custom-logon-ui-s-in-windows-vista.aspx)

  [image: 1]

Comment: Note: Obviously if you want to delve into this further the relevant place to ask for help would be StackOverflow.

Comment: To notice what loginui.exe does (eg:- functions,libs) and then write in a programming language. Am I right? @Karan

Comment: Yes, you essentially need to code your own custom GINA replacement (XP) or Credential Provider (Vista+). There are APIs provided and you can extend them to implement your own look or auth mechanism.